# fetching information from data - data mining practical techniques

Tags: data-mining

i am developing an online book store using php and mysql. now i want to implement some data mining techniques like recommending related books and so on.

i want to know what are the best resources to get some useful practical techniques to implement such things.

thx in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an awesome book: [Programming Collective Intelligence: Building Smart Web 2.0 Applications](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596529325)

The examples are in Python. Not hard to understand them, though.

Answer (score 2):

Often discrete mathematical "strongest path" finding algorithms are used. If you want a quick look at how the algorithms work, check out [this PDF](http://yury.name/webguide/02webguide.pdf). It contains examples with websites you maybe familiar with, such as last.fm and it's recommended bands and popular pages among friends on Facebook.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not of enough reputation points to add a comment to Nick D's post, so let me just reassert that the Collective Intelligence book is exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You might have heard of Netflix prize, a competition for recommendation systems.

Also, I personally don't recommend the book mentioned above. It only gives you some concept, if you want to build a system, the content there is far from what a decent system needs.

http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Collective-Intelligence-Building-Applications/product-reviews/0596529325/ref=cm_cr_pr_hist_2?ie=UTF8&showViewpoints=0&filterBy=addTwoStar

Answer (score 0):

you can take a look at the collection of tutorials on Mysql
http://www.dataminingtools.net/browsetutorials.php?tag=mys